# Laravel Project is Serving without .env file

Tags: laravel

If  .env is removed on my Laravel project the command

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

Causes this error

```
ErrorException  : file_get_contents(/folder/projectlocation/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at //folder/projectlocation/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96


{

file_put_contents(
$this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), 

preg_replace(

$this->keyReplacementPattern(),

'APP_KEY='.$key,

file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())

));

}
```

However the `php artisan serve` command works `"Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>"`

I have cleared all the Laravel caches. Why will it serve but not fetch the .env file configuration?

Comment: What is the question? Env helper accepts default values, that might be the reason it doesn't throw exceptions with an empty project.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. All application config comes from the config files in the `config/` folder. Each of the options in here is configured to take either the value from the `.env` file or a default value.

For example, the application key in the [`config/app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L107) file:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
```

So when no value is set for `APP_KEY` in `.env`, the application key will be `null` (not recommended!).